# Servidor encerrando conexão ao consumir um mesmo serviço pela segunda vez

Tags: c#, wcf

Estou com um problema, ao consumir o mesmo método de um serviço por mais de uma vez, durante a primeira chamada o método funciona normalmente, porém, quando o mesmo método é chamado em outro trecho do código, com os mesmos paramêtros, uma exceção é disparada e o serviço nem chega a ser consumido. Seguem a baixo os prints das exceções e suas inner exceptions.

[image: Esta primeira imagem representa a exceção externa que é disparada]
Esta primeira imagem representa a exceção externa que é disparada, após percorrer as exceções internas chegamos até aqui:

[image: Percorrendo as exceções internas chegamos até esta aqui:]

A baixo segue o trecho de código referente a configuração do cliente que consome este serviço.

```
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICobrancaService"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             openTimeout="00:10:00"
             closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

O servidor **WCF** está rodando em projeto do tipo **Windows Aplication**, a comunicação é realizada através de **HTTP**. A baixo segue a configuração do serviço no servidor

```
  <service name="MEU_PROJETO.Implementations.CobrancaService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MEU_PROJETO/CobrancaService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MEU_PROJETO.Interfaces.ICobrancaService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

Tem alguma ideia sobre o que pode estar ocasionando este erro?

Comment: Que tipo de serviço? Como é feita a chamada? Como está o código do servidor que atende a esta chamada?

Comment: Vou editar a postagem para responder a suas perguntas

Comment: Essa é a intenção ***=)***

Comment: @jbueno edição realizada

Comment: Você não mostrou seu código de chamada do serviço, então aqui vai uma dúvida: você está usando o mesmo objeto para chamar o serviço em pontos diferentes do código?